# How to make default indentation for parenthesis the same as for braces in Eclipse in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, indentation

I would like to have the same indentation for parenthesis as for brace of multilined, like this

[image]

Currently it tries to "fix" me if autoformat into single line.

Comment: Be sure to rename your new Eclipse formatter to "holy war" because that formatting is sure to fail some code reviews.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this parameters in Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Formatter -> Edit profile/New -> Line Wrapping tab.
[image: For example]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in Eclipse:

Eclipse -> preferences -> Java -> formatter

press new, then play with the formatting options to match your style.

Comment: I didn't found appropriate things there.